# "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object" when setting cookies gotten from selenium to python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, cookies, python-requests

I wrote a selenium script to get the cookies of a site:

```
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

and i try to pass the gotten cookies to requests

```
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))

r = requests.Session()
for cookie in cookies:
    r.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])
```

but i am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\maxis\Desktop\demo.py", line 10, in <module>
    res = r.get('https://www.douban.com/people/49407893/', headers={'User-Agent': 'M',}, cookies=cookies[0])
  File "C:\Users\maxis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\maxis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 515, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\maxis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 443, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Users\maxis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 320, in prepare
    self.prepare_cookies(cookies)
  File "C:\Users\maxis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 582, in prepare_cookies
    cookie_header = get_cookie_header(self._cookies, self)
  File "C:\Users\maxis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\cookies.py", line 142, in get_cookie_header        
    jar.add_cookie_header(r)
  File "C:\Users\maxis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\cookiejar.py", line 1367, in add_cookie_header
    attrs = self._cookie_attrs(cookies)
  File "C:\Users\maxis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\cookiejar.py", line 1326, in _cookie_attrs
    self.non_word_re.search(cookie.value) and version > 0):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Please what is the cause and the solution to this.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: it's seems like cookie["value"] must be a string/bytes and it's not. Can you check this?

Comment: I have exactly same problem. Please share the solution if you solved this.